# Action Listeners in Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, japplet

I have a class  that uses Japplet. The form has 2 input fields and a button. It also has a TextPanel to display the information entered by the user. The problem that I am having is displaying that info entered on the text area using an Action Listener. I dont know what i am missing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;

public class CreatePanel extends JPanel
{
 private Vector accountList;
 private JButton button1;
 private TransferPanel transferPanel;
 final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
   final int ROWS = 50;
 final int COLUMNS = 50;



public CreatePanel(Vector accountList, TransferPanel tPanel)
 {
this.accountList = accountList;
this.transferPanel = tPanel;


JLabel label1 =new JLabel("Account ID: ");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Amount: ");
JTextField accountID = new JTextField();
JTextField amount = new JTextField();


button1 = new JButton("Create an Account");



JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLUMNS);
textArea.append("No account");
textArea.setEditable(true);

JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
infoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
infoPanel.add(label1);
infoPanel.add(accountID);
infoPanel.add(label2);
infoPanel.add(amount);
infoPanel.add(button1);

add(infoPanel);

ActionListener listener = new ButtonListener();
button1.addActionListener(listener);

JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
textPanel.add(textArea);

   add(textPanel);




  }



   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {



   } //end of actionPerformed method
 } //end of ButtonListener class

} //end of CreatePanel class
```

Comment: You've deleted all your pertinent code making your question unanswerable -- why? I've rolled it back to its previous state so that it makes more sense to us.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- First and foremost, please put in the effort to format your code well. If it is not well formatted (such as the random wild indentations you're currently showing), we won't be able to understand your code well, and you will often make errors. Each code block should be indented the same amount, I usually use 2-3 spaces (one or the other and keep it consistent). Also, one line of empty white space is plenty.
- As for your problem, your fields should not be local to the constructor but should be class fields so that methods of the class can access them. In particular your JTextArea. Otherwise your ButtonListener won't be able to recognize the JTextArea variable since the variable's scope will be limited to the block that it was declared in -- here your constructor.

So change this:

```
public class CreatePanel extends JPanel
{
 private Vector accountList;
 private JButton button1;
 private TransferPanel transferPanel;
 final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
   final int ROWS = 50;
 final int COLUMNS = 50;



public CreatePanel(Vector accountList, TransferPanel tPanel)
 {
this.accountList = accountList;
this.transferPanel = tPanel;


JLabel label1 =new JLabel("Account ID: ");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Amount: ");
JTextField accountID = new JTextField();
JTextField amount = new JTextField();


button1 = new JButton("Create an Account");



JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLUMNS);
textArea.append("No account");
textArea.setEditable(true);

// .... etc
```

to this (please note formatting changes as well):

```
public class CreatePanel extends JPanel {
  public static final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
  public static final int ROWS = 50;
  public static final int COLUMNS = 50;

  private Vector accountList;
  private JButton button1;
  private TransferPanel transferPanel;
  private JTextField accountID = new JTextField();
  private JTextField amount = new JTextField();
  private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLUMNS);

  public CreatePanel(Vector accountList, TransferPanel tPanel) {
    accountList = accountList;
    transferPanel = tPanel;

    JLabel label1 =new JLabel("Account ID: ");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Amount: ");

    button1 = new JButton("Create an Account");

    textArea.append("No account");
    textArea.setEditable(true);

    // .... etc
```

and now ButtonListener can access the textArea field.

Answer (score 0):

Combine [getText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) of your `JTextField` with `JTextArea` [append(str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29);

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i've misinterpreted your question in someway but within the actionPerformed method of your ButtonListener class - you should be reacting to the ActionEvents which are passed in.